# Whats the logic behind the output

Tags: c

Why does the following code prints 64 for i and 4 for j.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define sqr(a) a*a
void main()
{
    int i;
    i=64/sqr(4);
    int j=64/16;
    printf("%d\n",i);
    printf("%d",j);
}
```

**Output shown below**

[image]

Comment: classical "I forgot to protect my macro": `sqr(a) a*a` => `sqr(a) ((a)*(a))`. Probably a duplicate

Comment: What's `64 / 4 * 4` evaluate to in C? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence might help

Comment: Eg. What is the difference between `64/4*4` and `64/((4)*(4))` ? Recall your basic mathematical expression priorities you learned in grammar school. What had *highest* priority ? What had *equal, left to right* priority ?